# Nearest neighbor algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, nearest-neighbor

I have my algorithm of the nearest neighbor and I am trying to go through all the points in a cycle. The length of the path is calculated as the sum of Euclidean distances between adjacent points on the path as what I did in the function "dist". The problem is it doesn't print the last point for some reason.

```
Input style:
n      #number of points
x1, y2 #coordinates of the point
x2, y2
...

example:
4
0 0
1 0
1 1
0 1
it gives me output >> 1 2 3 
the desired output should be >> 1 2 3 4
```

```
from math import sqrt

n = int(input())
points = []

for i in range(0, n):
    x, y = list(map(float, input().split()))
    points.append([x,y])


def dist(ip1, ip2):
    global points
    p1 = points[ip1]
    p2 = points[ip2]
    return sqrt((p1[0] - p2[0]) ** 2 + (p1[1] - p2[1]) ** 2)


circuit = set()
start_vertex = 0
dark_side = set(range(n)) - {start_vertex}

visited_islands = []
current_vertex = start_vertex
while len(dark_side) > 0:
    min_distance = None
    best_v = None
    for v in dark_side:
        if ((min_distance is None) or
                (min_distance > dist(current_vertex, v))):
            min_distance = dist(current_vertex, v)
            best_v = v

    visited_islands.append(current_vertex+1)
    circuit.add((current_vertex, best_v))
    dark_side.remove(best_v)
    current_vertex = best_v
# visited_islands.append(visited_islands[0]) #going to the start when done
print(*visited_islands)
# print(len(visited_islands))
```

Comment: You are doing your `while` loop using the variable `dark_side`. I didn't understood the initialisation of this variable:  `dark_side = set(range(n)) - {start_vertex}`. However, it is initialized with a dict `{1, 2, 3}`. So it will only loop 3 times before exiting.

Comment: To clarify the question, are you trying to find out the nearest neighbor for each point? Or are you finding a path? It looks like you are trying to do the former.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the last piece of your code, assuming that you are looking for the nearest neighbor for each point in the input.

```
circuit = set()
visited_islands = []
for current_vertex in range(n):
    min_distance = None
    best_v = None
    for v in range(n):
        if current_vertex == v:
            continue
        if ((min_distance is None) or
                (min_distance > dist(current_vertex, v))):
            min_distance = dist(current_vertex, v)
            best_v = v
    circuit.add((current_vertex, best_v))
    visited_islands.append(current_vertex+1)

print(*visited_islands)
print(circuit)
```

Output:

1 2 3 4

{(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0)}